# Как аннотировать экземпляр Vynil-файла при написании исходного NodeJS-кода на TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, gulp, typescript

В [@types/vinyl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/vinyl), интерфейс 'File' определён без module или namespace:

```
declare let File: FileConstructor;

interface File { ... }
```

В приведённом ниже gulp-таске, написанном на TypeScript, я пытаюсь обработать vynil-файл, но TypeScript выдаёт аж 4 сообщения об ошибке:

```
return gulp.src(globSelection)
        .pipe(gulpPlugins.pug())
        .pipe(gulp.dest( (file: File) => {

          console.log(file);
          return '';
        }));
```

[image]

```
Error:(25, 26) TS2345: Argument of type '(file: File) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(file: File) => string'.
  Types of parameters 'file' and 'file' are incompatible.
    Type 'File' is not assignable to type 'File'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
      Property 'lastModified' is missing in type 'File'.
```

`Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.` - лишь общие слова, не указывающие, какой именно тип нужен. Причём если посмотреть `@types/vynil-fs` - там всё аннотированно именно так:

```
export function dest(getFolderPath: (file: File) => string): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream;
```

Как же следует аннотировать callback в `gulp.dest`?

Comment: вы же можете просто тип не указывать, он автоопределится компилятором и вашей IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gulp.dest ждет функцию, которая принимает File из модуля vinyl, а вы пытаетесь передать ему функцию, которая принимает File из какого-то другого модуля.

Проверьте внимательнее все что вы наимпортировали, и сделайте так чтобы идентификатор File был импортирован из правильного модуля:

```
import * as File from 'vinyl';
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! К сожалению, пока не могу проверить его работоспособность, потому что как только исправил эту ошибку, возникло много других, потому исправление этих ошибок займёт ещё некоторое время.

Comment: Смог наконец проверить Ваше решение. Не знаю, за что Вас минусанули, но оно работает. Ещё раз спасибо Вас за ответ!